# Handling NaN values in a feature representing prioritization ranking

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data, data-imputation

I have a data set like so

```
ID EmailRecOrder IPRecOrder DeviceRecOrder Spam
1  NaN           NaN        NaN            1 
2  22            12         NaN            1
3  1             7          14             0
4  4             4          NaN            1
```

The RecOrder columns are rankings of how important they are. For example a EmailRecOrder of 1 means is high priority. Some of these rows won't have a ranking though and are left as NaN.

How should I handle something like this if I want to put it in a machine learning model.
I don't want to remove rows where there are NAs. Should I just set NaN to some random number like -99 since rankings can't be negative?

I want to remove

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just set NaN to some random number like -99 since rankings can't be negative?

No, you probably shouldn't.

It depends on the meaning, as always: in this case, does NaN means that it can be any priority level, even a very high one? Or does it mean that the person who enters it doesn't have any idea about the priority? Or they consider that it's not even worth entering a priority level, i.e. it's very low priority?

If you answer these questions of expert knowledge, it would be easier to decide the best way to handle these values.

Comment: NaN means that they haven't been given a priority - meaning that they aren't that prioritized. For example Email might have only 100 prioritizations. Any other email without a Nan Prioritization would be prioritized less than those 100 ranked ones. Would it still not make sense to set the NaNs to -99 in this case?

Comment: @bananaboy in this case, since 1 is high priority I assume that the priority level decrease when the value increases, i.e. 100 is less priority than 1. So it's more logical to replace NaN with a very high value, for instance 99. Keep in mind that a ML algorithm would take the order into account, for example create a condition 'priority<3' which represents a very high level.